# DataStax-Examples Netlify not able to launch with webpack-dev-server error Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: webpack, cassandra, webpack-dev-server, netlify, datastax-astra

Trying to initialize brand new "JAMStack + Netlify + Astra + Cassandra" with a new DSE.

```
$ netlify dev
◈ Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Overriding command with setting derived from netlify.toml [dev] block: yarn webpack-dev-server
◈ Functions server is listening on 42051
◈ Starting Netlify Dev with #custom
$ /workspace/todo-astra-jamstack-netlify/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:

/workspace/todo-astra-jamstack-netlify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object. (/workspace/todo-astra-jamstack-netlify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/workspace/todo-astra-jamstack-netlify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
◈ "yarn webpack-dev-server" exited with code 1. Shutting down Netlify Dev server
error Command failed with exit code 1.
I tried the same locally npm -v 7.6.3 throws same error.
```

Changing package.json to

```
"webpack": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

Importing with Legacy parameteres doesn't throw errors:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

But has warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/node-uuid/uuid.js 59:18-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Projects\DSE\todo-astra-jamstack-netlify\node_modules\node-uuid'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

And not able to save any data to the Astra table.

Steps to reproduce:
Create new DataStax Astra db/keyspace
Launch Netlify as described here: https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/todo-astra-jamstack-netlify#readme
See the error
Expected behavior
Application React To-Do saves data and ToDo list.

Comment: It works for data write but not read with the following combinations locally but not from Open Workspace on GitPod:

"webpack": "^5.4.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"

"webpack": "^4.16.3",
"webpack-cli": "3.3.9",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.7.1"

npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Could you try pulling the latest version of the app, deleting your node_modules and running npm install, then netlify dev?